# android:gravity acting strangely

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and have written a sample code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:text="sample1"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="4"


        />

    <TextView
        android:text="sample2"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#F90"
        android:textColor="#F09"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center"

         />

    <TextView
        android:text="sample3"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#F09"
        android:layout_weight="3"
         />

    <Button
        android:text="Press"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#F09"
        android:layout_weight="4"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

In textView2 id i changed layout_width to fill parent so that android:gravity attribute could be tested but when i set it to some value like center,bottom or top all other views also behave the same way?

Comment: what do you mean by "gets set"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use gravity its like real gravity, another planet inserted into the solar system and things go round different. If you have 2 items with gravity 1 they both are the same gravity they both take the same room. If another item enters the same system it depends how it compares to the gravity of whats there already as to what happens. Match parent expands to meet the outside. Wrap content shrink wraps the widget. I hope this explains it good enough in a non-technical kind of way.

Comment: I think your explanation should get not less than 1000 points.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
1.  Set a Layout_gravity on your main layout
2. Then set gravities for each of the child components

Check this code (with only gravity attributes included):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >

    <TextView
        android:text="sample1"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="left"    
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="sample2"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:gravity="right"

         />

     ...

</LinearLayout>
```